# No welcome screen on Windows GeoServer install

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows-10

I'm installing GeoServer version 2.18.0 on Windows 10, but not getting the welcome screen.

I'm using instructions found [HERE](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html), I've installed OpenJDK, and the startup.bat file ran successfully, but no welcome screen (as per step 6), or anything else for that matter, no desktop shortcut or anything listed in installed programs.

Any ideas?

To add I've also tried Oracle java as well. Also the Start.jar file does the same thing as the startup.bat file, or at least what I read in the command line seemed the same.

Per questions below:
Both the OpenJDK and Oracle java are 17.

@BradHards, good point on staying to one version, there are so many results when I search how to install that I have mixed things up it looks. Also I'll try sticking to 2.24.

Update:
So some progress, I'm getting a weird message at the beginning of the install:

```
*Welcome to GeoServer!
```

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17
The GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is not defined.
Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_HOME to the following directory:
C:\Geoserver
The GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR environment variable is not defined correctly.
Temporarily setting GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR to the following directory:
C:\Geoserver\data_dir
Please wait while loading GeoServer...*

Problem solved! The versions after a certain release do not have a welcome screen, you just go straight to the admin webpage.
Please mark as closed.

Comment: which versions of Java do you have installed?

Comment: The link you have provided is for 2.24.x. Following instructions that match your install version will probably help (especially for java versions, as alluded to by Ian). Also, 2.18.x is well out of support, so you probably don't want to do that on a production system.